# getting a "Uncaught TypeError: control.childrenByPropertyId is undefined" error with alpaca.js

Tags: alpacajs

I'm trying to use alpaca.js to populate a database.

I'm wanting to populate a set of form fields based on an ajax lookup on one field. I want to do an autocomplete on a hotel name field and populate other fields based on the hotel selected, e.g. number of rooms, number of floors, address, phone, etc.

My test code produces an "Uncaught TypeError: control.childrenByPropertyId is undefined" error.

I'm assuming that there is some mismatch of Javascript libraries.

My example code (I've modified urls by adding some spaces):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hotel Form</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn. bootstrapcdn. com/ bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn. jsdelivr. net/npm/alpaca@1.5.27/dist/alpaca/bootstrap/alpaca.min.css">

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code. jquery. com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn. bootstrapcdn. com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs. cloudflare. com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn. jsdelivr. net/npm/alpaca@1.5.27/dist/alpaca/bootstrap/alpaca.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="hotel-form"></div>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Define the schema for the form
      var schema = {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "hotel": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Hotel",
            "autocomplete": {
              "url": "hotels?q=%QUERY",
              "dataType": "jsonp",
              "displayKey": "name",
              "valueKey": "id",
              "cache": true,
              "limit": 10,
              "templates": {
                "suggestion": Handlebars.compile("<div>{{name}} - {{address}}</div>")
              }
            }
          },
          "numRooms": {
            "type": "integer",
            "title": "Number of Rooms"
          },
          "numFloors": {
            "type": "integer",
            "title": "Number of Floors"
          },
          "address": {
            "type": "string",
            "title": "Address"
          }
        }
      };

      // Define the options for the form
      var options = {
        "fields": {
          "hotel": {
            "type": "search",
            "size": 40,
            "placeholder": "Type the name of a hotel",
            "helper": "Select a hotel from the list",
            "removeDefaultNone": true
          }
        },
        "form": {
          "buttons": {
            "submit": {
              "title": "Submit"
            }
          }
        },
        "postRender": function(control) {
          // When the hotel field changes, populate the other fields
          control.childrenByPropertyId["hotel"].on("change", function() {
            var hotelId = this.getValue();
            if (hotelId) {
              $.getJSON("hotels/" + hotelId, function(data) {
                control.childrenByPropertyId["numRooms"].setValue(data.numRooms);
                control.childrenByPropertyId["numFloors"].setValue(data.numFloors);
                control.childrenByPropertyId["address"].setValue(data.address);
              });
            }
          });
        }
      };

      // Render the form
      $("#hotel-form").alpaca({
        "schema": schema,
        "options": options
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I figured it out.  The 'postRender' should be part of the 'options' object.  It should be at the same level as the 'schema' and the 'options' objects.